# Python for in loop looping 5 times for every object in list

Tags: python, json, loops, bigdata

So I have a large JSON array that looks something like this:

```
[
  { "name": "(((", "handle": "/handle/20.500.12657/50523" },
  {
    "name": "01 Contents; Indian Recordings (Schomerus 1929)",
    "handle": "/handle/20.500.12657/24765"
  },
  {
    "name": "01 The Complete Historical Collections 1899\u20131950, Indian Recordings (Schomerus 1929)",
    "handle": "/handle/20.500.12657/24768"
  },
  {
    "name": "02 Guiding principles of the edition; Indian Recordings (Schomerus 1929)",
    "handle": "/handle/20.500.12657/24770"
  },
  {
    "name": "03 Editors' preface; Indian Recordings (Schomerus 1929)",
    "handle": "/handle/20.500.12657/24769"
  },
  ...
]
```

in python I load it and loop through it like this:

```
import json;

handles = open('data/handles.json');
data = json.load(handles);

for i in data:
    id = str(uuid.uuid4().fields[-1])[:10];
    try:
      #retrieves content from external source
      document = {
            '_id': id,
            'name': name,
            'description': description,
            'author': authors,
            'isbn': isbn,
            'language': lang,
            'license': license,
            'license_url': licenseUrl,
            'date_published': date,
            'location': location,
            'keywords': keywords,
            'publishing': publishing,
            'publishing_url': publishing_url,
            'category': category
          };

          ins = db.insert_one(document);
        except Exception as e:
          # log error
```

The json array consists of 13 000 unique objects, the length of the `data` is exactly the same as number of the objects in the json file, however when I look into DB, for every object there are exactly 5 duplicates. All of the json data is 100% unique, so I don't really see how that is possible, am I looping through it wrong ? The stuff inside of the loop shouldn't affect how many times it loops, so I dunno where is the problem.

Also, what I might be relevant: The code runs on Ubuntu server and is started with pm2. –

Comment: Note: I am a JavaScript developer, this is a side script to accompany a node app, and the reason why we choose python is that it involves huge chunks of data and manipulation with it, so I don't have a lot of python experience, so I might be missing something really simple here.

Comment: Probably the error is in the code that saves the data to the db, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Or perhaps you've run this code five times, thus saving five copies of each item to the db...

Comment: @JohnGordon I can add that, but it's a bit big and mainly consist of retrieving data, however all the code inside of the loop should only get executed for the length of the data itself, right ?

Comment: Also, what I might be relevant: The code runs on Ubuntu server and is started with pm2.

Comment: @JohnGordon updated the question with requested details

Comment: Are you sure that the database was empty?

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard yes, 100% sure.